# Is triggering an event in Laravel Job a good practice?

Tags: laravel

I have:

- App based on Laravel 9
- Laravel Passport (API)
- Two models: `Schedule` and `TimeSlot` (`Schedule` hasMany `TimeSlot`).
- I use Laravel Job to generate time slots for a schedule (running `php artisan queue:work --timeout=0`)
- When the job finishes creating time slots in the background I want to emit an event `event(new TimeSlotsCreated($schedule));` to notify Pusher that time slots have been created.

Is this possible? Is this a good practice to trigger events in Laravel jobs?

Comment: Yes, why not? It's not illegal)